# How can I check if one string can be obtained from another by swapping two characters?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I'd like to write a function which takes word1 and word2, both words' length are equal. 
My goal is to check if word2 can be produced from word1 by swapping two different characters. Only one swap is enabled.
And if it can, which are those two characters.

For example:

```
word1: sale,
word2: lase,
function should return 'swap s l'

word1: and,
word2: dna,
function should return 'swap a d'
```

I have no idea how to start this task. 
(Cases like no word given, words are not the same length, etc... are handled). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @spc explained:

```js
function areEqualIfSwapped(A, B) {
     if(!A || !B || A.length != B.length)
          return 'error';
     var chars = A.split('');
     for(var i = 0; i < chars.length-1; i++){
          for(var j = i+1; j < chars.length; j++){
               var current = [].concat(chars);
               var temp = current[i];
               current[i] = current[j];
               current[j] = temp;
               var str = current.join("");
               if(str == B)
                    return 'swap '+current[i]+' and '+current[j];
           }
      }
      return 'error';
 }
 console.log(areEqualIfSwapped('and','dna'));
 console.log(areEqualIfSwapped('sale','lase'));
 console.log(areEqualIfSwapped('baba','bbaa'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried with a few inputs and sometimes it's not correct, for example:
console.log(areEqualIfSwapped('baba', 'bbaa')); I get error. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You can start by using nested`for` loops.

1. The first loop will start from `outerIndex = 0` the next will start from `innerIndex = outerIndex + 1`.
2. Outer loop will run till `word1.length - 1`
3. swap characters of `word1` at each index and verify with `word2`
4. You can easily save both characters in variables
5. if you find a match, break out of loop
6. Done!